# Rename all Pivoted Values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

I have stored values in `Fields` table, `Name` column. Here are list of names which should go as column names, for It I use `PIVOT`. I need to add `1` to all selected names.

It should be something like this:

Before pivot:

```
Column name:   |  Name     |        
               |  Jeniffer |                                      
               |  Jason    |
               |  Jack     |
```

After pivot:

```
Column names: | Jennifer1  | Jason1 |  Jack1 |
              -- It should go as column names
              -- And on each of name add 1
```

I have code for `PIVOT`, It's successfully do It, just problem Is how to add unit `1` to all selected values?

This is part of my code from stored procedure:

```
SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ','
FROM   (    SELECT  Name -- Here selecting names which should be renamed
    FROM    Fields
    WHERE   Id Between 50 And 82
) a 

SET @cols   = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)
SET @sql    = 'SELECT * FROM 
    (
        SELECT FF.Name AS [NamePiv]                     
        FROM  ......................
        WHERE ......................                                
    ) x 
    PIVOT
    (
        MIN (Val1)
        FOR NamePiv IN (' + @cols + ') 
    ) p'

EXEC Sp_executesql @sql, N'@param1 NVARCHAR(60), @param2 TINYINT, @param3 NVARCHAR(80)', @param1, @param2, @param3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a variable `@selectCols` and store aliases in it:

```
DECLARE @selectCols varchar(max) = ''
SELECT @cols += ([Name]) + ',', @selectCols += ([Name]) + ' [' + ([Name]) + '1] ,' 
FROM ...

SET @selectCols   = LEFT(@selectCols, LEN(@selectCols) - 1)
SET @sql    = 'SELECT ' + @selectCols + ' FROM 
            ( ...
```

Comment: Thank you for an answer. Are really I need to use `SET @sql    = 'SELECT ' + @selectCols + ' FROM`? Instead of `SELECT * FROM...` Now It nothing returning. No errors, but just nothing returning

Comment: Have you trimmed the trailing comma of @selectCols?

Comment: The same after I use this `SET @selectCols   = LEFT(@selectCols, LEN(@cols) - 1)` nothing returning

Comment: Does it return something when trying `SET @sql = 'SELECT ' + @selectCols + ' , * FROM`? I don't have the tables so I could not test it. But it should work when providing explicit aliases...

Comment: No, still nothing returned. Also tried to change `FOR NamePiv IN (' + @cols + ')` to `FOR NamePiv IN (' + @selectCols + ')`, but still nothing returned.

Comment: Forgot to give `@selectCols` an initial value, so it is always set to `null` as `null` + <anything> yields to null. Edited Answer.

Comment: So what inital value should be?

Comment: Just an empty string `''`. I edited the declaration in my answer already.

Comment: Should I use: `FOR NamePiv IN (' + @selectCols + ') ` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70372/discussion-between-flo-and-infinity).

Comment: And I need both of lines? `SET @selectCols   = LEFT(@selectCols, LEN(@cols) - 1)` and `SET @cols = LEFT(@cols, LEN(@cols) - 1)` ?